# how to count the result of a inner join function

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

```
select item_id
from orders inner join
     items
     on item_id.orders = id.items
```

(i need the counts for the result of this function)

Comment: if we replace inner join with subquery and do count(*) that should give the result

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont do that ? :

```
select count(*)
from 
orders 
inner join items on item_id.orders = id.items
```